# AWS on/off switcher on WEB page

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a question

My company use one of the AWS servers to show demos for our customers, and we don't need this server running 24/7. My question is how can I configure some switcher on main company site to switch on switch off needed server(EC-2).

Answer (score 1):

Expose some API endpoint that your site can call any time you trigger this switch.

This endpoint could use AWS CLI to start and stop the instance.

eg. START when you click 'Enable' from your site
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html

and STOP when you click 'Disable' from your site
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html